# Laravel session and table column hide show with jquery for user preference

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.8

I have created table column hide and show with jquery, now I need to create user preference table column hide and show by Laravel session. For example, if any user selects id and catalogue name the selected user will only see id and catalogue name after login his page each time. How can I create user preference Laravel session table column hide and show with jquery?

```js
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      var column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
      $(column).toggle();
  });
  

        
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});
```

```css
.onoffswitch-content{
   display: flex;
}
.onoffswitch-content-1{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
.onoffswitch-content-2{
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.onoffswitch-content-3{
    display: flex;
     align-items: center;
}
.ml-1{
 margin-left: 5px;
}
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #0adc1e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #ED1B24;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="onoffswitch-content">
        <div class="onoffswitch-content-1">
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="id" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="id" tabindex="0" checked>
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="id">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-1"><p>ID</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-content-2">
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="catalogue" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="catalogue" tabindex="0" checked>
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="catalogue">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-1"><p>Catalogue Name</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-content-3">
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="category" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="category" tabindex="0" checked>
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="category">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-1"><p>Category</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>



<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="id">ID</th>
        <th class="catalogue">Catalogue Name</th>
        <th class="category">Category</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="id">56797</td>
        <td class="catalogue">DIESEL S NENTISH W EU-39</td>
        <td class="category">Jeans</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? please elaborate more